# How did you change the griddata in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

here is a vue.js grid data sample.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/grid-component.html

How can I change the value in the demo variable in real time? (use json format)

Answer (score 0):

You have to emit method from child component to parent component.

i showed how to emitting method  to parent, and editting data.  it's working but i ignored sorting. When u sorted table all indexes are changing and editing action is failing. Because actions column is always constant . U can try this example without sorting. And u can understand how to make it.

```
 methods: {
saveIt: function() {
  this.gridData[this.editingNow]["power"] = this.editPower;
  this.gridData[this.editingNow]["name"] = this.editName;
  this.EditDiv = false;

},
test: function(sayim) {
  this.editName = (this.gridData[sayim]["name"]);
  this.editPower = (this.gridData[sayim]["power"]);
  this.editingNow = sayim;
  this.EditDiv = true;
}
```

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/z4boaerx/)